# OpenVINO validation_app: [warning] No images processed

Tags: inference-engine, openvino

I'm trying to run OpenVINO Inference Engine sample validation_app. According to [OpenVINO IE sample: Validation_app](https://software.intel.com/zh-cn/articles/OpenVINO-IE-Samples#validation...) , I've prepared my dataset like this:

```
<path>/dataset
              /0/image0.bmp
              /1/image1.bmp
```

When I run validation_app with:

```
./validation_app -i /home/chan/Desktop/predict_inceptionV3/dataset -m '/home/chan/Desktop/pbModel/IRmodel/PredictModel.xml'
```

warning comes out:

```
[ INFO ] InferenceEngine: 
    API version ............ 1.4
    Build .................. 19154
[ INFO ] Parsing input parameters
[ INFO ] Loading plugin

    API version ............ 1.5
    Build .................. lnx_20181004
    Description ....... MKLDNNPlugin
[ INFO ] Loading network files
[ INFO ] Preparing input blobs
[ INFO ] Batch size is 1
[ INFO ] Device: CPU
[ INFO ] Collecting labels
[ INFO ] Starting inference

[ INFO ] Inference report:
    Network load time: 57.1487ms
    Model: /home/chan/Desktop/pbModel/IRmodel/PredictModel.xml
    Model Precision: FP32
    Batch size: 1
    Validation dataset: /home/chan/Desktop/predict_inceptionV3/dataset
    Validation approach: Classification network
[ WARNING ] No images processed
```

Considering the .bmp image is in 700x460 and the input shape of the .xml file is 1x3x299x299, I tried:

```
./validation_app -i /home/chan/Desktop/predict_inceptionV3/dataset -m '/home/chan/Desktop/pbModel/IRmodel/PredictModel.xml' --ppType ResizeCrop --ppWidth 299 --ppHeight 299
```

But the WARNING is still the same.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using folder structure - put your images into a single folder and create a text file with content:

image0.bmp 0
image1.bmp 1

use path to file as -i argument for validation app.

If you creating file inside a folder with images - use just image names, if outside this folder - use full path.